# Custom animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, customization, jquery-animate

I found a javascript snipplet, which blurs an image using canvas. Now I want to animate this using jquery.

The snipplet can be called like this:

```
stackBlurImage( sourceImageID, targetCanvasID, radius, blurAlphaChannel );
```

So I was wondering, if there is some animation method, which I can pass just the duration (optional the easing - I don't need that for now) of the animation and a callback function, which gets called on any animation step with the no of the current step and the total steps. Then I could compute the blur value and call the function above.

Comment: What do the innards of this snippet look like?